# How can I make the progress bar animation run first after clicking on the "search" button? Android studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, progress-bar

The problem is that the progress bar only starts when the data has been processed. And I want it to run before processing the data, right after pressing the search button. What am I doing wrong?

whole fragment code

```java
package com.app.comicslibrary.MenuFragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.comicslibrary.Jsoup.ParseBookInfo;

import com.app.comicslibrary.MainActivity;
import com.app.comicslibrary.MenuFragments.ListActions.AddPosition;
import com.app.comicslibrary.MenuFragments.ListActions.ModelCollectView;
import com.app.comicslibrary.MenuFragments.SearchMenu.SearchListAdapter;
import com.app.comicslibrary.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<ModelCollectView> listParseComics;
    ArrayList<ModelCollectView> selectedComics;
    SearchListAdapter searchArrayAdapter;
    private ProgressBar loadingBar;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

        EditText searchLine = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchLine);
        Button searchButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        ListView searchList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewSearch);
        Button saveSearchButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveSearch);
        loadingBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);

        listParseComics = new ArrayList<>();

        //search and display result list
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void  onClick(View v){
                String textSearch = searchLine.getText().toString();

                if(textSearch.isEmpty() || textSearch.length() <= 3){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Введите более 3 символов в строку поиска", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                setLoadingProgressBarVisible();

                ParseBookInfo getInfo = new ParseBookInfo(getContext());
                try{
                    int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                    if (SDK_INT > 8)
                    {
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                                .permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                        listParseComics = getInfo.searchComicsInfo(textSearch, 1);//change numberpage later
                        searchArrayAdapter = new SearchListAdapter(container.getContext(), listParseComics);
                        searchList.setAdapter(searchArrayAdapter);
                    }
                }catch(IOException e){
                    Log.d("PARSEERROR", "Search comics is fail");
                }
            }
        });

        //select position and call add menu
        selectedComics = new ArrayList<>();
        saveSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listParseComics == null || searchArrayAdapter == null){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Нет данных для добавления", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                boolean []statusItems = searchArrayAdapter.getChecked();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddPosition.class);
                for (int i = 0; i < statusItems.length; i++) {
                    if(statusItems[i]){
                        ModelCollectView selectedItem = listParseComics.get(i);

                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        selectedItem.getImage().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

                        intent.putExtra("bytesImages" + i, bytes);
                        selectedItem.setImage(null);
                        selectedComics.add(selectedItem);
                    }
                }
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("selectedItemsInSearch", selectedComics);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setLoadingProgressBarVisible(){
        ((MainActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
                loadingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

The text of the log is displayed immediately, but the progress bar does not appear (function **setLoadingProgressBarVisible()**)

Comment: Are you supporting SDK level  from 8. First you can use above 21 and search comics should run on background task. It'll shows properly. Another suggestion Don't create new adapter fro the every search. Just update the list to your adapter

Comment: @GobuCSG Thanks. I put the search for comics in the background thread, as you wrote, and it worked.

Comment: Happy to hear... You are welcome... You should follow basic instructions... All the best for your future 